# how to create a UIBackgroundTask to send data when app is in background?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I m under delphi berlin. My app is in background listening for location updates. When their is a location update in background i need to send the data to a server, but as i read on the internet i need to do this inside a `UIBackgroundTask` else the app will enter again in the background before the data is actually send. Any idea how to do this under delphi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should get you started:

```
uses
  Macapi.ObjectiveC, iOSapi.Foundation, iOSapi.CocoaTypes, iOSapi.UIKit;

const
  UIKitFwk: string = '/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit';

type
  TBackgroundTaskHandler = procedure of object;

  // Fills in methods missing in Delphi
  UIApplication = interface(UIResponder)
    ['{8237272B-1EA5-4D77-AC35-58FB22569953}']
    function beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(handler: TBackgroundTaskHandler): UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier; cdecl;
    procedure endBackgroundTask(identifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier); cdecl;
  end;
  TUIApplication = class(TOCGenericImport<UIApplicationClass, UIApplication>)  end;

function SharedApplication: UIApplication;
begin
  Result := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
end;

function UIBackgroundTaskInvalid: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier;
begin
  Result := CocoaIntegerConst(UIKitFwk, 'UIBackgroundTaskInvalid');
end;
```

When your app receives a location update, you can make a call like:

```
TaskID := SharedApplication.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(DoExpiry);
```

Where DoExpiry is a method you define that handles when the OS indicates that your task time has expired. Check the result against UIBackgroundTaskInvalid.

When your task is finished, call:

```
SharedApplication.endBackgroundTask(TaskID);
```